# When does Map.keySet return null

Tags: java, dictionary, null, set

I'm reading some code which checks if the value returned by `Map.keySet` is `null`. The javadoc doesn't say anything about the return value of `Map.keySet`. It's an empty set if the Map doesn't contain anything.

When can the value returned by `Map.keySet` be `null`?

Comment: It should never return null.

Comment: I believe the documentation would have said that it would "_return null if ..._" so you should be safe with the implementation provided by java. You can of course define you own `Map` that break this.

Comment: I guess liberal sprinkling of null checks "just in case" is fall-out from the Billion Dollar Mistake of allowing all references to be `null` (instead of baking optionality into the type-system and have the compiler enforce it). Better safe than sorry (about a potentially possible NullPointerException)...

Comment: which implementation of `Map` are you using? is it from JDK or from a third-party library?

Comment: The map for which the check is being made is a LinkedHashMap

Comment: @saga, then the check is redundant, you could remove it, the view of a map can be empty, but never `null`

Answer (score 8):

It's definitely a lack of understanding of `Map.keySet` from the author of the code you're referring to. As you've mentioned the java doc clearly doesn't state that the `keySet` method will ever return `null`.

As an example, i've just looked at the `HashMap` implementation of the `keySet` method, it's defined as:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
      Set<K> ks = keySet;
      if (ks == null) {
          ks = new KeySet();
          keySet = ks;
      }
      return ks;
}
```

So, as you can see the value returned from the method is never null.

I've also checked several other implementations of the `keySet` method e.g. for `TreeMap`, `ConcurrentHashMap` et al but couldn't find any that would return null.

Answer (score 3):

`Map.keySet` should never return `null`. It is implicit in the documentation that `keySet` must never be `null`, because its content "tracks" the content of the `Map`:

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

This would be impossible to achieve if `keySet` was allowed to return `null`.

Standard implementations of the `Map` in Java, `HashMap` and `TreeMap`, do not return `null` from `keySet`. Since `Map` is an interface, one could develop an incorrect implementation of it that returned `null` for `keySet`. Programming for this remote possibility would not be a good idea, though.